# Centering of vertical columns of a table

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

Unfortunately, I cannot get the centering of the headers for the vertical columns of my table to work. I want to have the headers "B1" and "B2" vertically centered.

I could not find a solution for this particular setup.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|p{0.4\textwidth}|p{0.4\textwidth}|}
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{A1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}       {\textbf{A2}}\\
 \cline{2-3}
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{B1}}}} 
 &  \lipsum[1][1-3] 
 &  \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
 \cline{2-3}
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{B2}}}} 
 &  \lipsum[1][1-3] 
 &  \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
 \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}
\caption{none}
\label{tab: none}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, change to the column-type from `p{}` to `m{}` as [already suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/654127/31283) by Mico. However, I'd also suggest to remove unnecessary parts of the code, add `[origin=c]` in `\rotatebox` and slightly improved row spacing

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}      % m{} column-type + \extrarowheight
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbh]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}    % <--- added
    \setlength\extrarowheight{-1pt}       % corrects \arraystretch
    \begin{tabular}{c|m{0.4\textwidth}|m{0.4\textwidth}|}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{A1}}
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{A2}} \\
        \cline{2-3}
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{B1}}
            & \lipsum[1][1-3]
            & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
        \cline{2-3}
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{B2}}
            & \lipsum[1][1-3]
            & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
        \cline{2-3}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{none}\label{tab: none}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you load the `array` package and employ the `m` column type instead of the `p` column type for both data columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array} % for 'm' column type
\usepackage{multirow,graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|m{0.41\textwidth}|m{0.41\textwidth}|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{A1}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{A2}}\\
 \cline{2-3}
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{B1}}}} 
 & \lipsum[1][1-3] & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
 \cline{2-3}
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{B2}}}} 
 & \lipsum[1][1-3] & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
 \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}
\caption{none} \label{tab:none}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

For information, here is a way to construct that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    code-for-first-row = \bfseries,
    code-for-first-col = \rotate\bfseries
  }

\begin{NiceTabular}{m{0.41\textwidth}m{0.41\textwidth}}[hvlines,first-row,first-col]
   & \centering A1 & \centering\arraybackslash A2 \\
B1 & \lipsum[1][1-3] & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
B2 & \lipsum[1][1-3] & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\caption{none} \label{tab:none}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]